# React Material-UI - MUI: Expected spacing argument to be a number or a string, got [object Object]

Tags: debugging, material-ui

I have a general MUI-core debugging/support question, and [as instructed by the official documentation](https://mui.com/getting-started/support/) I am posting it here.

While working on a large project I can't isolate the cause of the following error message in the console:

> MUI: Expected spacing argument to be a number or a string, got [object
> Object].

I found this issue in the official repository, suggesting that I am setting a spacing value where I shouldn't be, but I can't figure out where exactly. Commenting out all elements in the JSX doesn't help - a blank rendered page still returns the error.

The console output is not helpful, as it's not pointing to the file containing the error:

```
MUI: Expected spacing argument to be a number or a string, got [object Object]. spacing.js:56
    createUnaryUnit spacing.js:56
    spacing createSpacing.js:26
    spacing createSpacing.js:25
    onUpdate jss-plugin-rule-value-function.esm.js:58
    onUpdate jss.esm.js:1337
    updateOne jss.esm.js:983
    update jss.esm.js:959
    update jss.esm.js:1245
    attach makeStyles.js:120
    useStyles makeStyles.js:233
    useSynchronousEffect makeStyles.js:187
    useStyles makeStyles.js:225
    WithStyles withStyles.js:56
    React 14
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3
```

Question: how do I debug this? Ideal answer would contain a list of things to check. I can't provide the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer examination the console output **did** point to invocation of

> ```
> WithStyles withStyles.js:56
> ```

I have found the *withStyles* wrapper in the export line of the application root component: that's why removing all of the elements in the tree did not prevent the error message from appearing.

I could then isolate the problem to the following property of *styles* argument that was being passed to *withStyles*:

```
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: theme.spacing,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
```

The particular style entry causing the issue was:

```
marginTop: theme.spacing,
```

*theme.spacing* is a function, and should have been called with parenthesis.

The following answers my question:

- Inspect console output by expanding the error message
- Inspect each entry in the call stack for clues as to where the error may be, corresponding each call to framework features that you use in your code